# Why does my app crash when using android.hardware.Camera.Open()?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I am re-writing an app for most versions of Android. The app is set to call `android.hardware.Camera.Open()` on launch. When the app launches it gives the error `Camera Error: Could not connect to camera`

The permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>`.
```

Why can't it connect to the camera?

Comment: have you added camera permission ??

Comment: @pankajkhedekar I have a working version of this app on the Amazon app store, so yes

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Are you checking runtime permissions?  As of v23, camera requires a runtime check as it can be revoked after installation.

Comment: The app crashes on launch after calling `android.hardware.Camera.Open()` and complains that it can't access the camera.

Comment: So as it turns out, I didn't have the permissions set up right. I'll have to tinker with that some more I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

The issue was simply a matter of capitalization. The line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.camera"/>` should actually read `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`. This happened because `camera` is a hardware feature, while `CAMERA` is a permission.

Comment: Those are the most annoying issues to spot. Good eye.

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of android in order to use camera hardware there was enough to state proper permissions and uses in android manifest, but since the Marshmallow version has appeared it's not enough to run the app anymore. As there is also need to enable runtime permissions. Consider using similar code, and suit it to your project, as it gives You opportunity to check and enable permission.

```
  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            cameraPreview.initializeCamera();
        } else {

        }
        return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        cameraPreview.initializeCamera();
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


   public void requestCameraPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            },
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void requestPermissionWithRationale() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.string.no_cam_permission, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.snackbar_action_grant, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestCameraPermission();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    } else {
        requestCameraPermission();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are runtime permissions so complicated?

Comment: Some of the apps in the past were running camera and other hardware like voice recording without any notice of user, so the developers decided to just ask user each time, wether he wants to let the app use such a hardware first.

Comment: Might be useful for You https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Comment: So apparently the official version of my app works just fine, no runtime permissions. I will have to look into this.

Comment: You can vote me up if my answer was helpful for Ya :))

Comment: I'll try it later. Reviewing manifest files right now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hope it'll help You :))

Comment: @Raid hah dude when I first saw Your manifest I've noticed there was a lower case in camera word, just though it was too trivial to cause Your crash :d

Answer (score 0):

Use Camera for Deprecated

Below is the code

***UPDATE --->***

```
  @Module
public class CameraModule {

    @Provides
    CameraSupport provideCameraSupport() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            return new CameraNew(context);
        } else {
            return new CameraOld();
        }
    }
}
```

and then for Old target :

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CameraOld implements CameraSupport {

    private Camera camera;

    @Override
    public CameraSupport open(final int cameraId) {
        this.camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrientation(final int cameraId) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        return info.orientation;
    }
}
```

for New Target :

```
  public class CameraNew implements CameraSupport {

    private CameraDevice camera;
    private CameraManager manager;

    public CameraNew(final Context context) {
        this.manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public CameraSupport open(final int cameraId) {
        try {
            String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(CameraPreview.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

                return null;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraIds[cameraId], new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                    CameraNew.this.camera = camera;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
                    CameraNew.this.camera = camera;
                    // TODO handle
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                    CameraNew.this.camera = camera;
                    // TODO handle
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO handle
        }
        return this;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public int getOrientation(final int cameraId) {
        try {
            String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraIds[cameraId]);
            return characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            // TODO handle
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because I need the app to run on older devices (pre-api21)